# How to get value of checkbox in tix

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tix

i can get status of checkbox but How to Get value of checkbox in `Tix`.

```
from tkinter import tix

class View(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.makeCheckList()

    def makeCheckList(self):
        self.cl = tix.CheckList(self.root, browsecmd=self.selectItem)
        self.cl.pack()
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1", text="C:/")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL1.Item1", text="subitem1")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL2", text="some folder")
        self.cl.hlist.add("CL2.Item1", text="test")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL2", "on")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL2.Item1", "on")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1", "off")
        self.cl.setstatus("CL1.Item1", "off")
        self.cl.autosetmode()

    def selectItem(self, item):
        print (item, self.cl.getstatus(item))

def main():
    root = tix.Tk()
    view = View(root)
    root.update()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Expected output**

if i click on checkbox `c:/` then it should print `c:/`.I want the value of checkbox.

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps all in `hlist`

[Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.tix.html) for more informations about `hlist` sends to [tcl/tk documentation](http://tix.sourceforge.net/dist/current/man/html/TixCmd/tixHList.htm) and then you can find

```
pathName item_cget entryPath col option
```

But it doesn't work as I expected

```
value = self.cl.hlist.item_cget('CL1.Item1', 0, 'text')

# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "text"
```

You have to use `"-text"` instead of `"text"`

```
value = self.cl.hlist.item_cget('CL1.Item1', 0, '-text')
```

Comment: How to find parent path ? 
(pathName info parent entryPath ). This is given in document but i don't find any useful explanation about it.
Can you tell me how to find parent path?

Comment: doc shows code in tcl/tk language. In your code `pathName` means `self.cl.hist`, `entryPath` means  `CLI1` or `CLI1.Item1`, etc. `parent` probably means `self.root`

Comment: self.cl.hlist.info(self.root,'CL1') is it correct ?

Comment: I think it is correct. Try it and you will see error or not :)

Comment: It is giving error :   TypeError: pack_info() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: i checked documentation and I see `parent` is bold - it means it will be function `info_parent()` in python. ` 
`parent_id = self.cl.hlist.info_parent('CL1')`

Comment: Thank you very much...i got the answer

Comment: BTW: try `help(self.cl.hlist)` in code and it will display all functions - sometimes with description.